# How to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am presented with the following problem:

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$

After simplifying the left hand side expression:

$\frac{1}{2^{2n}}(\frac{(2n - n)!n!}{2n!}) = \frac{1}{2^{2n}}({\frac{n!}{2n!}}) = \frac{n!}{2^{2n+1}}$

And using Stirling's approximation, I get:

$\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n}{2^{2n + 1}}$

However, I'm not sure how to get from:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n}{2^{2n + 1}}$

to

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$

Comment: Some things are going wrong in the line after : " after simplifying the left expression ..."

Comment: You've made the classical mistake of mixing $(2n)!$ with $2(n!)$. There should be a name for this error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you might have simplified the expression wrong.

$$\binom{2n}n=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

After applying Stirling's approximation, we have

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\approx\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^{2n}}{\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n\right)^2}=\frac{2\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^{2n}2^{2n}}{2\pi n\left(\frac ne\right)^{2n}}$$

Note that $\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{\pi n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$, while the $\left(\frac ne\right)^{2n}$ and $2$ on both sides of the fraction cancel out, giving us

$$\binom{2n}n\approx\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Can you continue from here?